# XBOne controller driver issues. How to use Dolphin and Steam on the same driver

Tags: steam, controllers, xbox-one, windows, dolphin-emulator

Recently I discovered that the current Xbox One controller drivers are bunk and you have to use much older drivers in order to get background window control. This is critical when doing link play with VBA-M and Dolphin with more than one player as the window you play in is not the same window receiving controller input.

[These drivers](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=xinput) fix the problem (first one in the list). However, there is still one critical issue. When you switch to these drivers you can play games on Dolphin and VBA-M, but the controller is no longer recognized by Steam, or any game launched by Steam. It might extend to other platforms too, but I've not tired.

Controllers configured in this manner are recognized and function in Window's controller properties, but not by the Xbox accessories app. You have to uninstall the device and re-install the latest official drivers (sometimes multiple times) before it finally starts working again. This is clearly not optimal.

Is there a way around this issue? Is there a magic driver version that works for both? Even a script that would quickly swap between driver versions that I can throw on my desktop would at least be a solution better than what I have now.